# Reset Android Studio settings to default setting on linux

Tags: android, android-studio

everyone. I used to develop android application on Mac. Recently I installed android development environment on my Thinkpad which running Xubuntu.

I imported the Android studio settings on Mac to the  Android studio on Xubuntu via File-> import settings.

But after I have done this, everything goes wrong. The hotkey, the java path ecc.

I tried to delete android studio, and download it again, but the settings are still there.

On the internet I can find almost nothing about this, does anyone know how to reset Android Studio settings to default setting? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's very simple. Depending on your AndroidStudio version, the settings are stored in `~/.AndroidStudio`, `~/.AndroidStudio1.1` or `~/.AndroidStudio1.2`.

Open a terminal and run the following code:

`ls -a | grep Android` # See which of those three folders above you have. Then rename each of the settings folders you have with the appropriate `mv` command:

```
mv .AndroidStudio .AndroidStudio.bak
mv .AndroidStudio1.1 .AndroidStudio1.1.bak
mv .AndroidStudio1.2 .AndroidStudio1.2.bak
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have AndroidStudio1.2 installed, I renamed ".AndroidStudio1.2" to  ".AndroidStudio1.2.bak" and the system created another ".AndroidStudio1.2"  folder for me. Thanks for your time!

Comment: This dose not reset settings, this way you reset everything, th SDK, plugins everything downloaded ...

Comment: It Worked ,Thanks Man

Answer (score 11):

The file location on Linux has changed since this question was first asked.  As of Android Studio 4.2, you may remove all the settings and cache using:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio*
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio*
rm -rf ~/.cache/Google/AndroidStudio*
```

Answer (score 1):

To restore with same method of the colleague with windows, but now with ubuntu, by the terminal.

1. To know what folder relating android on the PC, using the command
   (ls -a | grep Android), without parentisis.

For example, in my case, these:
- Android
- .AndroidStudio3.0
- AndroidStudioProjects
- AndroidV

2. In my case I got the folder .Android studio, I proceed to delete with the command
   (rm -rf ~/.AndroidStudio3.0) without parentisis.
3. I return to check with the command (ls -a | grep Android), without parentisis. if the  folder .Androidstudio3.0 was deleted, in my case.

   - Android
   - AndroidStudioProjects
   - AndroidV

then run Android Studio launcher, Vooalaaa !!
Configure as the first time and Resetting.

Apologize for my bad orthographies and other details, but with that method I solved my Android Studio in ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Had somewhat the same problem but in windows machine. Solved it by mapping a different settings folder than renaming it. This is how I fixed it : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33021782/4747587