# Android Studio file type extension definitions

Tags: android-studio

I created a new file (with .frag extension) within Android Studio, and a window "Register New File Type Association" popped up. I wasn't paying attention and I selected "Open matching files in associated application" which now makes it so any time I try to open a *.frag file it opens in Gedit (which I had open at the time of the file creation). I checked file types in Settings but I didn't see an option to change the association definition. I want my *.frag files to open in Android Studio.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[register-new-file-type-association-dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/register-new-file-type-association-dialog.html)

I just made the same mistake.

1. Go to Setting
2. write 'file types' on the search box
3. select the 'File types' under 'Editor'
4. find the one you assigned and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting Android Studio back to default settings using this link: [Reset Android Studio settings to default setting on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828325/reset-android-studio-settings-to-default-setting-on-linux)