# How to point settings location of Android Studio to a different custom location?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have the following problem. I have two Android Studio in my system. One is the stable version and the other is the Canary version. When I updated them, unfortunately I messed up in the 'Complete Installation' screen. It asked for importing settings from custom location and I gave the wrong location.

Initially by Canary version was pointing to **C:\Users\myUserName.AndroidStudioPreview1.4** and Stable version was pointing to **C:\Users\myUserName.AndroidStudio1.4**. But after the update both are pointing to **C:\Users\myUserName.AndroidStudio1.4**.

Because of this there are so many problems. I want my Canary version to point to  **C:\Users\myUserName.AndroidStudioPreview1.4**. How do i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out the solution.

1. Go to the folder where you installed your Canary version of Android Studio (most likely in Program Files).
2. Go to bin folder
3. Open both **studio.exe.vmoptions** and **studio64.exe.vmoptions** in a text editor.
4. In that, change the following line **-Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio1.4** to **-Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudioPreview1.4**. Or to any other Setting folder that you want.

Works perfectly.